# Boolean value in RAIL API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created RAILS API where I am sending Boolean value True(true) or False(false). Application works fine if I send "true" value in boolean field but it throws error message i.e "Filed can't be null" if I pass "false". Please find the below example-

{ "Product": {"Name": "product1" , "Active":false} }

{ "Active": [ "can't be blank" ] }

{ "Product": {"Name": "product1" , "Active":true} }

success Message

Comment: Sounds like you are validating that the field can't be false/nil

Comment: is there a settings in a model that defaulting value to nil, from non true?